# Como instalar o pacote de idiomas (português-br) no VS code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Como instalar o "Pacote de Idioma para o VS Code em Português Brasileiro"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Vá na aba de Extensões(Ctrl+Shift+X)
2. procure por essa extensão `Portuguese (Brazil) Language Pack for
   Visual Studio Code`
3. depois da instalação aparecerá uma caixa de diálogo pedindo a
   confirmação para a troca de linguagem aceitei clicando no botão Yes
4. depois disso ele deve reiniciar sozinho já com a linguagem
   brasileira instalada.